# How to create function symbols dynamically in pyDatalog?

Tags: python, logic-programming, datalog, pydatalog

For example I have this kind of rules in Datalog:

[image]

How do I create these rules dynamically in pyDatalog using "load"?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried already ?  What did not work ?